# Adding <link> tag to aspx page causes VS2008 window to suddenly shrink

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-8.1

I am having a really odd and frustrating problem with Visual Studio 2008 on a Windows 8.1 Pro Surface.

Every time I try to add the following line to the `<head>` of any .aspx page

```
<link href="scripts/style_v2_1.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

my Visual Studio window, after a few seconds, jumps down to about a quarter of its original size, and the fonts shrink with it becoming tiny and almost unreadable.

In fact just typing

```
<link
```

is enough to make it go haywire.

[image: Everything is tiny except some buttons]

Adding it to the `<body>` and also inside the `<Content>` tag of a page using a Master page has the same result. Anywhere else - outside the page content, in Web.config file, does *not* result in the strange behaviour.

Re-sizing the window or minimizing/maximizing it does not fix the font size, I have to close and reopen it to restore normality (and if the offending line of code is still on screen then the cycle repeats).

Has anybody any idea what is going on or if there is a fix/workaround for this? The application is basically unusable if I need to link stylesheets to a web page using the above method.

Obviously running VS2008 on Windows 8 (or at all in this day and age!) is not ideal but it should surely be compatible nonetheless?

---

Note:
A probably related thing I have noticed previously is that when I resize the Text Editor by dragging down from the top of the Error List, the result is fine but the resizing "graphic" appears in the wrong place - almost as if some part of the application "thinks" the window is a quarter of the size it really is:

[image: related-resizing-issue]

Comment: Please don't be mad but your really should just bite the bullet and install Visual Studio 2015 Community edition as it's free.

Comment: Not my choice I'm afraid!

Comment: That said I generally do this particular dev work on another PC so it's not necessarily the absolute end of the world if I can't fix this.